# How to design a wave chandelier procedurally?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I want to design a wave chandelier and would prefer to minimize my efforts by using modifiers.
I'd like to use something that allows the curve to be controlled too but can't figure how to use any of the modifiers for this purpose.

[image: A wave chandelier looks like this]

Comment: Check animation nodes or sverchok addon

Comment: Make an array across, then conform it to a curve using a Curve Modifier. After that, use another Array Modifier going down. The final bottom jewels that are larger can use the same curve but be offset with their meshes lower than their object origins. Maybe I can post an answer in more detail later if I have time.

Comment: Forget my previous comment. When I ran through this in my head I didn't account for the bending in the Curve Modifier, which turns out to cause undesirable distortion. But there are a couple of other ways to do this, and I'm putting an answer together.